# Using forms in partial views in asp.net core razor pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, get, partial-views, razor-pages

I have the following structure:
`SelectLoc.cshtml`:

```html
@model SelectLocModel

<div class="dropdown">
    <form method="get">
        <select asp-for="Location" asp-items="Model.Locations"
                class="btn btn-secondary" formaction="Partials/SelectLoc" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        </select>
    </form>
</div>
```

`SelectLoc.cshtml.cs`:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Json;

namespace AdminPortal.Web.Pages.Partials
{
    public class SelectLocModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly HttpClient httpClient;

        private readonly string key = "FAKE TOKEN";

        public string Location { get; set; }

        public List<SelectListItem> Locations { get; } = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem { Value = null, Text = "Select Location" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "Kothrud", Text = "Kothrud" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "Dhanakawdi", Text = "Dhanakawdi" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "Karvenagar", Text = "Karvenagar" },
            new SelectListItem { Value = "Wakad", Text = "Wakad" },
        };

        public SelectLocModel(HttpClient httpClient)
        {
            this.httpClient = httpClient;
        }

        public void OnSubmit()
        {

        }

        public void OnGet()
        {
            
        }

        public void OnGetSubmit()
        {

        }

        public async void OnGetLocation()
        {
            string geocodeRequest = $"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={Location}&key={key}";
            Location jsonResponse = await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<Location>(geocodeRequest);
        }
    }
}
```

---

I know, that there isn't any useful code in any of the methods, but I want the form to use the `OnGet` handlers in the code-behind file. It somehow keeps calling the `ctor`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you mean you use the page as partial page in other pages?And when submit form,it will not go to `https://localhost:xxx/SelectLoc?Location=xxx`.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to go to `https://localhost:xxx/Partials/SelectLoc?Location=xxx` when submit form,you can add `action="/Partials/SelectLoc"` in form.

SelectLoc.cshtml:

```
@model SelectLocModel
<div class="dropdown">
<form method="get" action="/Partials/SelectLoc">
    <select asp-for="Location" asp-items="Model.Locations"
            class="btn btn-secondary" formaction="Partials/SelectLoc" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    </select>
</form>
```

result:

[image]

Comment: Yes,I also not add @page.Can you show the page you use the partial view.And why you have SelectLoc.cshtml.cs in a partial view?

Comment: *why you have SelectLoc.cshtml.cs in a partial view?* that is because, that module is to be present on every page. So, it's basically in `_Layout.cshtml`

Comment: Also, `action=stuff` expects the partial to be a page

Comment: If you delete @page of SelectLoc.cshtml,the handlers in SelectLocModel will not work,because it is not a razor page.In the situation.You need to combine Mvc with razor page.and let form call the action in controllers.

Comment: There are no controllers. The model is MVVM